# Summarize cols in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to combine two columns with multiple IDs and combine the labels at the same time. The original data.frame looks like this:

```
#          id_v     label
#          100      „garage“
#          100      „garage“
#          101      „carport“
#          102      „garage“
#          103      „garage“
#          103      „carport“
```

By transformig it, the targe data.frame should look like this:

```
#          id_v     label
#          100      „garage, garage“
#          101      „carport“
#          102      „garage“
#          103      „garage, carport“
```

Thank you very much for your help

i have tried to merge the columns using the merge function, but i have not yet found a solution to combine the labels.

Comment: `aggregate(label~id_v, df, toString)` should solve your problem